# When should JetCreator or SoundPool be used?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I'm trying to make an app and I would liek to try to implement the optimal solution for multiple, simutaneously playing, programmatically selected sound effects.

I really appreciate the help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends:

**Mediaplayer:**

Not good for simultaneous playing (you need multiple MP objects), the response time and especially the prepare() methode take a lot of time.
Therefore synchronizing is quite impossible.

**SoundPool:**

Good for small MP3.files (size limt ~1mb, ~30sec)
Easy to implement
A lot faster than Mediaplayer. Mostly used for "sounds" and not a for complete "piece of music"

**Jet Player/JET Creator**

Used for MIDI files, quite difficult to install (you need python, wx python in order to use JET creator ...). 
Very fast response, good for simultaneous playing of several tracks!

Any further questions? do not hesitate to ask!

best regards